# How do I have more stamina than my stamina limit?

Tags: dragalia-lost

My stamina bar for Dragalia Lost shows that I have 29/20 stamina while at level 2. [According to Gamepress](https://dragalialost.gamepress.gg/player-level-experience-table), I shouldn’t be able to get this much stamina until level 9.

How did I get 29 stamina when my max stamina is 20?

[image: 29/20 stamina points]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way stamina works in this game is that, when the stamina bar drops below its max, in this case 20, it will begin to automatically refill to its max size.

There are multiple ways in which a player can obtain stamina other than just waiting for it to refill:

- **Leveling up**: The player will receive stamina each time they level up their account. This amount scales 1 for 1 with their stamina bar size.
- **Purchases**: The player can purchase 100 stamina for 40 Diamantium or 40 Wyrmite.
- **Consumable items**: The player can consume Honey to obtain stamina. Exquisite Honey will provide 30 stamina, Quality Honey will provide 20 stamina, and Normal Honey will provide 10 stamina.

**When these methods are used, they will refill the stamina by the amount specified, ignoring your current maximum stamina.** It should be noted that there is a hard stamina cap at 999 stamina. Per [a Reddit post from another player](https://www.reddit.com/r/DragaliaLost/comments/9maqbw/guide_dragalia_lost_beginner_guide_power_level_to/):

> Stamina piling up doesn't really matter as it goes up to as much as
>   999 I believe. You get 6 with every level and when you run out of
>   these, you will spend a lot of time waiting as host with stamina, so
>   don't waste these.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not 6 with each level, but one full bar's worth. So in the case of the OP they would have gotten 20 upon level up.

Comment: Also, normal honey is 10, quality is 20, exquisite is 30.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I’ll update the post when I have some time today.